# Which function is faster $f_1$ or $f_2$

Tags: asymptotics

I'm trying to compare two functions asymptotically, are there any simple solution for this?

$f_1(n) = 3n^2 +   {\dfrac{100\log n}{\sqrt n}}   $

$f_2(n) = 10 + \dfrac{2(n! - 5n)}{n^{3/2}}  $

Which one is better?

Comment: What makes a function “better” than another function?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong title, i meant which one is faster

Comment: Probably meant faster

Answer (score 0):

Please show some of your work or an attempted solution. One hint I can give you is to look up and use Sterling's approximation for the factorial.